# Get local file with Jquery through WebView on Android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, webview

I'm working on an hybrid app for Android. I'm using JQuery executing into a WebView.

From JQuery I need to read a local file from the asset/www folder.

Testing in a browser my code is working fine but inside the WebView on Android the file seems not to be found without any error message returned.

My code to load the Webview:

```
webViewMenu = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webViewMenu);
// Add javascripInterface to the webviews
webViewMenu.addJavascriptInterface(myJavaScriptInterface, "AndroidFunction");
// Open webview with Chrome
webViewMenu.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
    @Override
    public void onExceededDatabaseQuota(String url, String
    databaseIdentifier, long currentQuota, long estimatedSize,
    long totalUsedQuota, WebStorage.QuotaUpdater quotaUpdater) {
        quotaUpdater.updateQuota(estimatedSize * 2);
    }
});
WebSettings settingsMenu = webViewMenu.getSettings();
settingsMenu.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
settingsMenu.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
settingsMenu.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
settingsMenu.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
String databasePath = this.getApplicationContext().getDir("database", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getPath();
settingsMenu.setDatabasePath(databasePath);
webViewMenu.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/menu.html");
```

My JQuery code reading the local file:

```
$.get('../sql/models.sql', function(sql){
     console.log("info: init the models database with SQL: " + sql);
     sqlProcessRequest(sql, "ModelsLoading");
     },
     function(e){
     console.log("error: loading models.sql file!");
});
```

On a browser, le file is well read but within the WebView, neither the success nor the error function is called.

My folder tree is as follows:
    www/
        index.html
        js/
            code.js
        sql/
            models.sql

Any idea... Thanks very much

Comment: Have you considered using phonegap.com?

Comment: For a performance point of view, we would avoid to user Phonegap. Why this question, do you think it's not possible to access a local file from a web view ?

Comment: Have you had any luck with this issue? I've found this tutorial, http://helpmeco.de/2012/2/serving-android-webview-resources-with-content-providers but I haven't tested it out quite yet.